# If else with array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I need help with my code. The if statement will check session for user privilege. If it's admin it will show the `active()` array and if not the `active()` will not be shown. Is there anyway I could optimize this code? I don't want to coded the same code twice just to deactivate the `active()` array?

```
if($_SESSION["s"]["user"]["typ"] == 'admin') {
$form["tabs"]['dns_soa'] = array (
    'title'     => "DNS Zone",
    'width'     => 100,
    'template'  => "templates/dns_soa_edit.htm",
    'fields'    => array (
    ##################################
    # Begin Datatable fields
    ##################################

        'update_acl' => array (
            'datatype'  => 'VARCHAR',
            'formtype'  => 'TEXT',
            'default'   => '',
            'value'     => '',
            'width'     => '30',
            'maxlength' => '255'
        ),
        'active' => array (
            'datatype'  => 'VARCHAR',
            'formtype'  => 'CHECKBOX',
            'default'   => 'Y',
            'value'     => array(0 => 'N',1 => 'Y')
        ),
    ##################################
    # ENDE Datatable fields
    ##################################
    )
);
}
else {
$form["tabs"]['dns_soa'] = array (
    'title'     => "DNS Zone",
    'width'     => 100,
    'template'  => "templates/dns_soa_edit.htm",
    'fields'    => array (
    ##################################
    # Begin Datatable fields
    ##################################

        'update_acl' => array (
            'datatype'  => 'VARCHAR',
            'formtype'  => 'TEXT',
            'default'   => '',
            'value'     => '',
            'width'     => '30',
            'maxlength' => '255'
        ),

    ##################################
    # ENDE Datatable fields
    ##################################
    )
);  
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I must say thank you for the 5 people who is helping me. I use Nacereddine solution because he's/her answer is straightforward. Thanks again to DBDev, Nacereddine, Adrian Brown, Michael and Ben. What a great community we have here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be easy

```
$form["tabs"]['dns_soa'] = array (
    'title'     => "DNS Zone",
    'width'     => 100,
    'template'  => "templates/dns_soa_edit.htm",
    'fields'    => array (
    ##################################
    # Begin Datatable fields
    ##################################

        'update_acl' => array (
            'datatype'  => 'VARCHAR',
            'formtype'  => 'TEXT',
            'default'   => '',
            'value'     => '',
            'width'     => '30',
            'maxlength' => '255'
        ),
        'active' => array (
            'datatype'  => 'VARCHAR',
            'formtype'  => 'CHECKBOX',
            'default'   => 'Y',
            'value'     => array(0 => 'N',1 => 'Y')
        ),
    ##################################
    # ENDE Datatable fields
    ##################################
    )
);

if($_SESSION["s"]["user"]["typ"] != 'admin') {
    unset($form["tabs"]['dns_soa']['fields']['active']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I take a look at 4 other answers and I must say your solution is very easy to understand and clean.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
$form["tabs"]['dns_soa'] = array (
    'title'     => "DNS Zone",
    'width'     => 100,
    'template'  => "templates/dns_soa_edit.htm",
    'fields'    => array (
    ##################################
    # Begin Datatable fields
    ##################################

        'update_acl' => array (
            'datatype'  => 'VARCHAR',
            'formtype'  => 'TEXT',
            'default'   => '',
            'value'     => '',
            'width'     => '30',
            'maxlength' => '255'
        ),
    ##################################
    # ENDE Datatable fields
    ##################################
    )
);

if($_SESSION["s"]["user"]["typ"] == 'admin') {
    $form["tabs"]['dns_soa']['active'] =array (
            'datatype'  => 'VARCHAR',
            'formtype'  => 'CHECKBOX',
            'default'   => 'Y',
            'value'     => array(0 => 'N',1 => 'Y')
        );
}
```

And later on, to display, you can check for the existence of active with isset

```
if (isset($form["tabs"]['dns_soa']['active']))
{
    // do something with it
}
```

Comment: You can copy/paste faster than I can.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the array without the `$active` array first, then add it if the user is an admin:

```
$form["tabs"]['dns_soa'] = array (
    'title'     => "DNS Zone",
    'width'     => 100,
    'template'  => "templates/dns_soa_edit.htm",
    'fields'    => array (
    ##################################
    # Begin Datatable fields
    ##################################

        'update_acl' => array (
            'datatype'  => 'VARCHAR',
            'formtype'  => 'TEXT',
            'default'   => '',
            'value'     => '',
            'width'     => '30',
            'maxlength' => '255'
        )
    ##################################
    # ENDE Datatable fields
    ##################################
    )
);

if($_SESSION["s"]["user"]["typ"] == 'admin') {
  $form["tabs"]["dns_soa"]["active"] = array (
            'datatype'  => 'VARCHAR',
            'formtype'  => 'CHECKBOX',
            'default'   => 'Y',
            'value'     => array(0 => 'N',1 => 'Y')
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Soemthing like

```
$form["tabs"]['dns_soa'] = array ( 
'title'     => "DNS Zone", 
'width'     => 100, 
'template'  => "templates/dns_soa_edit.htm", 
'fields'    => array ( 
    'update_acl' => array ( 
        'datatype'  => 'VARCHAR', 
        'formtype'  => 'TEXT', 
        'default'   => '', 
        'value'     => '', 
        'width'     => '30', 
        'maxlength' => '255' 
    ),
    )
);

if($_SESSION["s"]["user"]["typ"] == 'admin') { 
     $form["tabs"]['dns_soa'][fields]['active'] = array (      
        'datatype'  => 'VARCHAR',      
        'formtype'  => 'CHECKBOX',      
        'default'   => 'Y',      
        'value'     => array(0 => 'N',1 => 'Y')      
    );
}
```

Havent tried it, but you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

```
// Presume user is NOT admin and populate $form
$form["tabs"]['dns_soa'] = array (
    'title'     => "DNS Zone",
    'width'     => 100,
    'template'  => "templates/dns_soa_edit.htm",
    'fields'    => array (
        'update_acl' => array (
            'datatype'  => 'VARCHAR',
            'formtype'  => 'TEXT',
            'default'   => '',
            'value'     => '',
            'width'     => '30',
            'maxlength' => '255'
        )
    )
);
##################################
# ENDE Datatable fields
##################################  

if($_SESSION["s"]["user"]["typ"] == 'admin') {

$form["tabs"]['dns_soa']['fields']['active'] = array (
##################################
# Begin Datatable fields
##################################
        'datatype'  => 'VARCHAR',
        'formtype'  => 'CHECKBOX',
        'default'   => 'Y',
        'value'     => array(0 => 'N',1 => 'Y')
    );
##################################
# ENDE Datatable fields
##################################
```

}